# in android, how would you extract the image from a imagebutton?

Tags: java, android, image

I have two imagebutton and I want to switch the image of each other so button a will have button b's image while button b will have button a's image. I tried to do this in my code, but it does not work

```
Bitmap temmp = a1.getDrawingCache();
a1.setImageBitmap(a2.getDrawingCache());
a2.setImageBitmap(temmp);
```

Comment: how you setimage for imagebutton??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow like this

```
buttona.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {            
  public void onClick(View v)  { 
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)v;  
    Drawable d11 = ib.getDrawable(); // this is the image u can get from that button
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to  [enable the drawing cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) before calling the `getDrawingCache()` with  `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`.